# How to access Rest API data hosted at other domain. Cross domain issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest, cross-domain

I can successfully access data from my local Rest api through JQuery, But when i tried to access data from remote Rest API (hosted at other domain) through JQuery, i got the error as Undefined.
How i solve cross domain problem ?

This is how i am using through JQuery.

```
function GetCompanyName(id) {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://novacompanysvc.azurewebsites.net/api/companies',
        type: 'GET',
        data:{ id:id },
        dataType: "text/xml",
    success: function (data) {
       if (window.DOMParser)
          {
          parser=new DOMParser();
          xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
          }
        else // Internet Explorer
          {
          xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
          xmlDoc.async=false;
          xmlDoc.loadXML(data); 
          }
       WriteResponse(data);
     },
     error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert('error');
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because the API end point you are accessing does not implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control).
If you run your code in Chrome and look at the console, you will see an error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://novacompanysvc.azurewebsites.net/api/companies?id=1. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

The solution is to change the API end point to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to either the wildcard `*` or to the domain where the page using the JavaScript code will be served from.

Comment: Thanks. How can i change API end point to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin? As i am newbie in JQuery stuff, Can you please give me solution by providing sample code ?

Comment: What language or framework is the API server written in? Depending on that, you will have to make some changes in the server code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem.

Now It is resolved by me.
Suppose you have two domain.
domain1 and domain2

you can use this technique.

Create a middle layer by using server side script in domain1, you can get the data from domain2 using java,PHP etc and then create a rest services in domain1 and use rest service in domain1.

Answer (score -1):

i have face this problem also. i fix this by

avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.

**For your own domain** serve all content as HTTPS and fix your links.
you put by: http// to https//

**For other domains** use the site's HTTPS version if available. If HTTPS is not available, you can try contacting the domain and asking them if they can make the content available via HTTPS.